# gallery with foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Currently i design a gallery with this form

[image]

i getting the imgs from a DB, the problem i'm facing is to maintain dat gallery structure with the images i get from db, i want to repeat that form every 6 images, i thought i could do a if-else, but it's not working, because my conditional overwrite eachother, for example if i put if(x % 2 == 0) class a this will overwrite if(x % 4 == 0) class b, and this is the code i use to get the data from db, and the foreach i want to fix

```html
<?php foreach ($imagenes as $imagen): 
  $control = $imagen['id_img']; //get the id from the img
?>
  <?php if($control % 3 === 0 || $control % 4 === 0){?>
 <li class="c">
    </li>
  <?php }elseif($control % 2 === 0 || $control % 5 === 0){ ?>
    <li class="b"> 
 </li>
  <?php }else{?> 
    <li class="a"> 
 </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, originally the ideas was to get automatically the videos from youtube with the api and put in the boxes, but i didn't know how to do it, so i change that for a table youtube_videos where the embed i saved and then i'll get it and put in the gallery, is not pretty but it works

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i thought the code i provide was enough, but ok, i'll do some css to show the structure

Comment: Not necessarily _more_ code is needed, just the _right_ code. The minimum required for us to reproduce the problem on our end, as written on [mcve].

Comment: Edit, that should be better =). Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: That's a lot of code IMHO

Comment: well basically the problem is right there, in the foreach

Comment: I'm not sure what happens, and what you expected to happen. If you think it'll help, ask a friend to check the grammar for you.

Comment: @AlexanderPulido How many numbers can be in $control variable? 1-5 or more?

Comment: i have the gallery as the image, how can i fill it with the data i get from the db maintaining the form?

Comment: @Rahul a lot, but after 6 the structure should repeat. That will be, class A (the larger box) -> class B (the small size box) -> class c (the middle size box) -> class c -> class b -> class a edit*

Comment: @AlexanderPulido You can work on the data in batches then. Create batches of 6 images and repeat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this-

```
<?php

$imagenes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
$temp_arr = [];
$c = 0;

foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {

    $temp_arr[] = $imagen;

    if(count($temp_arr) === 6) {

        echoRow();
        $temp_arr = [];
        $c = 0;
    }
}

function echoRow() {
    global $temp_arr;
    global $c;

    foreach($temp_arr as $control) {

        switch($c) {
            case 0: echo "\n$control c <br>";
            break;
            case 1: echo "\n$control a <br>";
            break;
            case 2: echo "\n$control b <br>";
            break;
            case 3: echo "\n$control b <br>";
            break;
            case 4: echo "\n$control a <br>";
            break;
            case 5: echo "\n$control c <br>";
            break;
        }
        $c += 1;

    }   
}

echoRow();
```

Above method creates batches of 6 to display your data.

Comment: this worked great for the gallery issue, but now i'm facing another problem, the base64_encore is not working when i try to assign the background

Comment: Can you be more specific? That comment isn't really all that helpful.

Comment: not neccesary, i find the solution using the same logic from your answer. Just had to add another temp for the imgs i was getting from the DB and add to the cases. Thansk for your help!